# Oracle SQL use a column as a query and then display the results over the original column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables.

The first table, named DATA, looks like:

```
DATE    NAME     DESCRIPTION
5/2     5        Orange Juice
5/4     2        Apple Juice
5/5     1        Cranberry Juice
5/6     1        Lemon Juice
```

The second table is called NAMES and looks like:

```
NAME_ID   NAME
5         Bob
4         Frank
3         Megan
2         Tim
1         Brian
```

I want to, query all columns from the DATA table and perform a lookup on the NAME column, have it grab that number, look that number up in the NAMES table and replace that data in the DATA table, NAME column, so I would get something like:

```
DATE    NAME     DESCRIPTION
5/2     Bob       Orange Juice
5/4     Tim       Apple Juice
5/5     Brian     Cranberry Juice
5/6     Brian     Lemon Juice
```

I am a total SQL noob, so my attempts so far have been google the crap out of this, and I keep getting lead to subqueries, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  It is usually one of the first things you learn when learning SQL.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need subqueries - but you do need joins. Sample data from line #1 - 10; query that does the job begins at line #12. I guess that "date" column actually *is* `DATE` datatype, but - for simplicity - I left it as a string.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  data (datum, name, description) as
  4    (select '5/2', 5, 'Orange Juice' from dual union all
  5     select '5/4', 2, 'Apple Juice'  from dual
  6    ),
  7  names (name_id, name) as
  8    (select 5, 'Bob' from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'Tim' from dual
 10    )
 11  -- query you probably need
 12  select d.datum,
 13    n.name,
 14    d.description
 15  from data d join names n on n.name_id = d.name
 16  order by d.datum;

DATUM NAME  DESCRIPTION
----- ----- ------------
5/2   Bob   Orange Juice
5/4   Tim   Apple Juice

SQL>
```